# Fair dice probability problem

Tags: probability

You  flip a coin 7 times and observe 2 heads and 5 tails.

Calculate the probability that the event that you observed might actually come from a fair coin.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Why does your topic say "dice"?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot calculate such probability because you don't know the distribution of the parameter $p$ of the Bernoulli experiment.

Anyway, you can know the probability of the outcome given that the coin is fair.

Assuming that is a fair coin,

$$P[Bin(7,.5)=2]=\binom 7 2 (.5)^2(.5)^5$$.

If that probability is small enough for you to accept it, you can reject that it is from a fair coin.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

Given that there are 2 heads and 5 tails, find the probability that 0.5 is the probability of flipping a head or tail.

Let p be the probability of flipping a head, $0 \le p \le1 $.

$P(p = 0.5| 2 \,heads \,and \,5 \,tails) = P(p = 0.5) * {7 \choose 2}0.5^7/\int_0^1 {7 \choose 2} p^2(1-p)^5 dp$

To be honest I don't know what $P(p=0.5)$ is. But the denominator is ${7 \choose 2}$ times the beta function $B(m+1, n+1) = m!n!/(m + n + 1)!$. In this case $m = 2$ and $n = 5$. For proof please refer to http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf solution to exercise 1.11. Hope this can help.